# Find hash value which is in a collection of nested arrays?

Tags: ruby

I have a collection of three arrays.

Each array has this structure:

```
Array > Array > Hash
```

How could most effectively get the value of a certain key in each of the three hashes?

**Update**

Current code:

```
collection.map{|c| c[0]}.map{|cc| cc[1]}.map{|ccc| ccc[:my_key]}
```

Comment: @coreyward +1. Also how about showing this collection and expected result?

Comment: OK, I've know updated with current code. It works, buy I'm curious if there are better (cleaner/more concise etc) ways to accomplish the same.

Comment: The question itself looks fundamentally wrong. `group_by` won't return array, but a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one go:

```
collection.map{|c| c.first.second[:my_key] }
```

As to whether there are cleaner way - it depends on what this collection represents, how it was obtained and etc. We have way too little information to help you clean it any further.

Comment: +1 for teaching me the existence of literal equivalent of the index position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatten` to simply make it an array of hashes, and then search for the key in them.

`collection.flatten.select{|key, value| key == :my_key}.map{|k,v| v}`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
collection.map { |(_,second,_),_| second[:my_key] }
```

This takes the second element of the first element of each item in your collection, and returns the `my_key` key in it.

```
collection = [[[{my_key: 1, yyy: 'zzz'},{my_key: 2, yyy: 'yyy'}],
               [{my_key: 3, yyy: 'zzz'},{my_key: 4, yyy: 'yyy'}]],
              [[{my_key: 5, yyy: 'zzz'},{my_key: 6, yyy: 'yyy'}, {my_key: 7, yyy: 'zzz'}],
               [{my_key: 8, yyy: 'zzz'},{my_key: 9, yyy: 'yyy'}]]]

collection.map { |(_,second,_),_| second[:my_key] }
# => [2, 6]
```